# Does a lattice in $PSL(2,\mathbb{R})$ stabilizing $\infty$ have a domain with vertex at $\infty$?

Tags: complex-analysis, hyperbolic-geometry

Suppose $\Gamma$ is a lattice in $PSL(2, \mathbb{R})$ acting on the upper half plane. Suppose that the stabilizer in $\Gamma$ of the point at infinity is nontrivial.  Does it then follow that the exists a Dirichlet domain for $\Gamma$ which has a vertex at infinity?

Comment: No: You also need to assume that the stabilizer is unipotent. Then the answer is positive and follows from the thick-thin decomposition of the quotient-orbifold. You do not even need to assume that $\Gamma$ is a lattice, only that it is discrete.